# Different authentication rules with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I try to setup different authentication rules for different url's in one spring application.

For all public rest requests `/rest/**` I want to setup basic authentication, for internal rest calls `/internal/**` I need ip based access so that some defined hosts can access without authentication.

I have tried the follwing setup:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("rest/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }

}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class Api2WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/internal/**").access("hasIpAddress('100.100.100.100/16')").anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

But if i call the internal endpoint from localhost i do not get an 403 error as i expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end after a lot of try and error i came up with:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/internal/**").access("hasIpAddress('100.100.100.100/16')").anyRequest().permitAll().anyRequest().denyAll();
}
```